# (JavaScript+PHP) How would I tell 40 buttons to each apply to the table row they're on, without 40 separate events?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Let's say that I have a big table of products. On each row, there's the product name, its price, and a "Rebate?" checkbox. Each product has two values associated with it: fullPrice and rebatePrice. If the rebate checkbox is selected, show rebatePrice; else, show fullPrice.

Using PHP, I can generate this table by creating a class for each product, issuing a DB query, and looping over the results creating one instance per row, like so.

```
// Get a MySQL resource with all of my available products.
$db = new mysqli('localhost','alibaba','opensesame','myFictionalStore');
$results = $db->query("SELECT * from productsForSale");

// Define a class that takes "product name", "price", and "rebate price" parameters, and builds a table row.
class item {
    function __construct($product,$price,$rebatePrice) {
        echo "
            <tr>
            <td>{$product}</td>
            <td>{$price}</td>
            <td class="rebate">{$rebatePrice}</td>
            <td><input type=\"checkbox\" /></td>
            </tr>
        ";
    }
}

// Instantiate that class so that every row in the result becomes a row in a HTML table.
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)) {
    new item($row['product'],$row['price'],$row['rebatePrice']);
}
```

This builds my table just fine. I do have a question, though, that I spent Sunday night on and can't quite figure out.

I want the checkbox in each table row to toggle between the full price, and the rebate price. How should I do this? I'm currently trying to use a JS `for` loop that builds an array of all checkboxes, an array of all rebate cells, and then says *on click of box [i], console.log rebate cell [i]*, just to make sure I've latched onto the right thing... but that never works, and I can't imagine why...

Comment: can we see the js code you've written?

Comment: You have a syntax error at `class="rebate"`

Comment: with javascript/jquery its easy ..

Comment: You should read the quirksmode.org articles about event handling: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html. They contain everything you need to know. If you are using jQuery, you should also read http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-basics/ and http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/. In short: You only have to bind one event handler to the root of the table and you can access the element that triggered the event inside the handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create like this

```
 $db = new mysqli('localhost','alibaba','opensesame','myFictionalStore');
    $results = $db->query("SELECT * from productsForSale");

    // Define a class that takes "product name", "price", and "rebate price" parameters, and builds a table row.
    class item {
        function __construct($product,$price,$rebatePrice) {
            echo "
                <tr>
                <td>{$product}</td>

                <td><span class="price">{$price}</span><span class="rebate">{$rebatePrice}</span></td>
                <td><input class="showPrice" type=\"checkbox\" /></td>
                </tr>
            ";
        }
    }

    // Instantiate that class so that every row in the result becomes a row in a HTML table.
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)) {
        new item($row['product'],$row['price'],$row['rebatePrice']);
    }
```

jquery is

```
$('.showPrice').change(function ()
{

    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {

        $(this).parent().prev().find('span').hide();
        $(this).parent().prev().find('span.rebate').show();
    } 
    else
    {
        $(this).parent().prev().find('span').hide();
        $(this).parent().prev().find('span.price').show();
    }
});
```

if you dont want to show rebate price on initial load

in css you can hide it.

```
.rebate
{
   display:none;
}
```

Comment: Instead of the whole `if...else` statement, you could just write `$(this).parent().prev().find('span').toggle();`. Since one element is hidden at the beginning, this will always toggle between the elements.

Comment: you have syntax error while assigning class name to `<td>`. please change `"` to `'` or add `\ `

Comment: @krishna ironically so do you in your answer around `"toggling[]"` :P

Comment: haaahaaaa forgot to change there. Thanks for mentioning

Answer (score 2):

change your php function like this

```
 function __construct($product,$price,$rebatePrice) {
        echo "
            <tr>
            <td>$product</td>
            <td class='price'>$price</td>
            <td class='rebate' style='display:none'>$rebatePrice</td>
            <td><input type='checkbox' name='toggling[]' /></td>
            </tr>
        ";
    }
```

and use the following jquery code

```
$('[name^=toggling]').change(function(e){

 if ($(this).prop('checked')==true){
   $(this).closest("tr").find(".rebate").show();
   $(this).closest("tr").find(".price").hide();
}
else
{
   $(this).closest("tr").find(".rebate").hide();
   $(this).closest("tr").find(".price").show();
}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

may be you can change your table like this

```
<td class='priceHolder' data-fullprice="{$price}" data-rebateprice="{$rebatePrice}">{$price}</td>
<td><input class='togglePrice' type=\"checkbox\" /></td>
```

Then using jquery when user changes the checkbox, you can change the price.

e.g.

```
$('td').on('click' ,'input.togglePrice' , function(){
    var elem = $(this).parent('td').prev('td');
    if ($(this).attr('checked')) {
        elem.html( elem.data(rebateprice) );
    } else {
        elem.html( elem.data(fullprice) );
    }
});
```

This is just an idea, you can work on this and improve it or change it as per your need.

Answer (score -2):

Just declare a separate form on every table row, and that should do it.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. Perhaps you misunderstood it. The OP wants it so that if you select a checkbox, the price displayed will toggle between including a rebate and not.

Comment: Was it wrong to assume that he's asking what's in the title? Lol.

Comment: @witherwind The title is rather ambiguous and should be edited IMO

Comment: Haha. I think so too. Because of the title, my answer was downvoted. :D

Comment: because the answer is unrelated to the question, it was downvoted

Comment: Because I misunderstood the question. Don't sweat it. This is pretty normal.

Comment: @witherwind it happens to the best of us ;)

Comment: Hahaha. I certainly agree. :D